# No option to map 'Lookup' type fields

Tags: webforms, crm

I'm using Salesforce suite & Salesforce webforms to map fields between Drupal and Salesforce. I can map every field type except the 'lookup' type because I don't have that as an option. Can I get a solution to it?

Thanks,

Suby

Comment: It's because you need a record ID to populate a lookup field. You would need to perform an initial query first to find the record that you want, store it's ID temporarily, then assign it. You will most likely need to do this in a hook while the entity is saving or prior to submitting the form, then setting the ID in a hidden ID field in the form_state so you can pass it to the Webform integration.

Comment: I realize this is old, but wanted to comment for future reference.